# How to close MessageDialog programmatically in WP app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a long running task in my WP app. `MessageDialog` must be opened before the task starts and when the task ends then `MessageDialog` must be automatically closed programmatically from the code. How can I achieve such behavior?

I've tried to use solution from some similar questions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516811/how-to-programmatically-close-a-messagedialog-in-win8-app-using-winjs), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698666/how-to-close-message-dialog-programmatically)):

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("test");
IAsyncInfo asyncInfo = dialog.ShowAsync();

await SomeTask();

asyncInfo.Cancel();
```

But this didn't help me. Message dialog remains opened.

Comment: Try using `AsyncCommand` instead of `IAsyncInfo`

Comment: @MicrosoftDN I can't find info about `AsyncCommand`. Can you provide a link to the documentation about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found a solution in another question:

[How to dismiss a MessageDialog from code in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795850/how-to-dismiss-a-messagedialog-from-code-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Short answer:

1. You can't close `MessageDialog` programmatically on Windows Phone.
2. Use `ContentDialog` instead if you need such behavior.